# AWS APIが403エラー

Tags: monaca, aws

Monacaでaws-sdk-jsの使用を試みていますが、以下のようにEC2系のAPIを使用すると、403エラーが返ってきてしまいます。同様のコードで別のリソース（S3やRoute 53等）への処理を試みるとエラーは返ってきません。

```
AWS.config.update({
accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
secretAccessKey: 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY'});
AWS.config.region='ap-northeast-1';                 

var e = new AWS.EC2();
e.describeRegions({}, function(er,da){
console.log("error: " + er);
console.log("data: " + da);
}
```

これは私の環境が原因なのでしょうか。Monacaに起因する制限事項なのでしょうか。コードの修正で対応できるのでしょうか。
原因や切り分け方法等、ご教授頂けますと幸いです。

Comment: IAM ポリシーでEC2へのアクセスは許可してますか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。許可しています。同じIAMアカウントで別SDKでアクセスした場合等は、取れるのです。。